# Retrieving all the new subscription videos in YouTube v3 API

Tags: youtube-api

I need to know the equivalent request in YouTube Data API v3 as this v2 request for retrieving all the new subscription videos.

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/newsubscriptionvideos
```

I have not seen any simple and clean requests that are as simple as the v2 version of the reques

Answer (score 26):

You can retrieve this information with the Youtube V3 API but it is incredibly inefficient:

- First get the channel ID from the username (one request).
- Now get the subscriptions for the channel (batchable - one request per 50 subs).
- Now get the playlists for each subscribed channel (batchable - one request per 50 subs).
- Get the most recent playlistItems for the "uploads" system playlist of each channel. (one request per sub).
- Get the video related to each playlistItem (batchable - one request 50 playlistItems).

You can now sort the videos by publishing date and print the most recent.

If you have 100 subscriptions and fetch 5 videos from each channel this will result in 114 API requests and use around 500 quota units (the daily limit is 50 million units). It will also take about 2 minutes to run if you don't parallelize the API calls.

This method does have a couple of benefits over using activites though:

- You can do it for any user with public account settings, not just the authenticated user, so it works like the V2 API in that respect.
- It won't randomly lose videos like the Youtube homepage does.

A full Python implementation is available: https://github.com/ali1234/ytsubs

Comment: You could also do a `search` to avoid getting playlists and playlistItems which would result in less requests. However, the quota consumption would explode with this method.
Alistair's method still seems to be the best at this time.

Comment: All this because Google deprecated the ```home``` parameter in the ```activities``` list YouTube API.

Comment: maybe this could work:
1) get users subscriptions by yt api
2) take all channel ids and make a request: https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id={}
3) order by date
4) ????
5) $$$ Profit $$$

Answer (score 7):

There is not an exact equivalent but you can get close with

> [youtube.activities.list(part=”snippet”, home=true)](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list)

then filter the one with [snippet.type](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities#snippet.type) = upload

Comment: Is there anyway to filter for the snippet.type = upload in the request itself?

Comment: There is an update on this in the works. You can track it from here: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=3946

Comment: Thank you very much! I will follow it.

Comment: This solution seems not to retrieve all the last uploaded videos (I miss some of them)

Comment: ```home``` is now deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who's interested in retrieving the newly uploaded videos "today" like how it's done in `/feed/subscriptions`, use "search API" ([link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)).

In this case, it requires 2 APIs. The search API and the subscriptions API ([link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list))

1. Get the channels IDs using the subscription API
2. For each channel id, use search Id with `channelId`, `publishedAfter` and `publishedBefore` parameters.
3. Then filter out results that have `items.length == 0`.

Then now, you can filter only the most recent videos uploaded by the subscribed channels.

---

**EDIT**: Search API costs 100 quota.:

> A call to this method has a quota cost of 100 units.

Playlist item API costs 3 quota:

> A call to this method has a quota cost of 1 unit in addition to the costs of the specified resource parts.

So ... it's a lot cheaper to cache uploads playlist ids from the "channels API" and use the playlist.

Or to be able to filter by publish dates like search API, use the Activities API which has `publishedBefore` and `publishedAfter` parameters.