# How to get user's subscriptions uploads

Tags: youtube-api

I'm currently developing a chrome extension that notifies you when one of your subscribed channels uploads a new video.

Now I'm having trouble finding the correct API method to aquire a list of recent uploads from the users subscribed channels, for example the list the user sees when he visits: https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions

I maybe know about a workaround, but that would be overkill: list all subscribed channels, and for each one of them list the latest videos of the uploads playlist (would be 2 requests per channel i think)
Can anyone help me out here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> There is not an exact equivalent but you can get close with
>
> youtube.activities.list(part=”snippet”, home=true)
>
> then filter the one with snippet.type = upload

[Was already answered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19640796/retrieving-all-the-new-subscription-videos-in-youtube-v3-api?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: This is not close enough for me: 1) the result is unordered and seems to ignore the publishedAfter flag 2) the result is always the same for like 3-4 hours (it's not up-to-date). i need on-time results for my app. see the problems with this here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451711/youtube-api-v3-activities-list-not-returning-expected-data)

Comment: Then all you can do is get subscribed channels and get the upload list for each.

Comment: like i explained in my opening post, that would make one refresh like 120 requests if the user has ~60 subscriptions. thats pretty intense. even if i save the uploads-playlist for each subscribed channel it would be X requests if user has X subscriptions, which is too many in most cases :/. If anyone wondered I found an open issue where google is aware of this issue: [https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=3946](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=3946)

Comment: @kentobi there are a few optimizations you can do, but not much. 100 subscriptions produces 114 requests and uses about 500 quota units. See new the answer I posted on the other question.