# YouTube API v3 method to get new subscription videos

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

There currently doesn't seem to be a way to get new subscription videos through the YouTube v3 API, i.e an equivalent to the "newsubscriptionvideos" method in v2 and the "My subscriptions" page on the website. "activities.list" with "home=true" is not sufficient because it randomly omits videos.

Most rececently, I came across this iOS app called [Tubex](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tubex-videos-music-for-youtube/id939906112?mt=8) that seemed to figure out a solution. Their feed is absolutely spot on so there is no way they are following what we are currently doing. Anyone have any idea what kind of workaround Tubex may be doing to get it so accurate?

Comment: looks like this is the only method at the moment http://stackoverflow.com/a/23620166/1810833

Comment: @Joe That is a very slow and inefficient way. If you download the Tubex app, they have VERY fast loading times and their feed is spot on :(

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I know how to do it with the ```subscriptions``` and ```search``` list apis, but that uses way too many api requests.